# Find the probability of $\max[X,Y]<\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed random variable on $[-1,1]$. Find the probability of $\max[X,Y]<\frac{1}{2}$.

I calculated it using graphically that the region where the where $[X,Y]$ is less than half divided by the total area *i.e.* $9/4*1/4=9/16$ but i have a doubt that this approach of mine has included the points where $\max[X,Y]=1/2$.

Comment: The probability of $\max(X,Y)=1/2$ is actually zero, so $P(\max(X,Y)<1/2)=P(\max(X,Y)\le 1/2)$. This is a consequence of the random variables having a probability density function.

Comment: means that $P(X=x)=0$ ,where $X$ is a continuous random variable.It is only defined on a interval $P(a<X<b)$.@angryavian

Comment: Can you explain $9/4*1/4=9/16$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are independent, let $M = \max\{X,Y\}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
P(M\leq 1/2) &= P(X\leq 1/2, Y\leq 1/2)\tag 1\\
&= P(X\leq 1/2)P(Y\leq 1/2)\tag 2\\
&=\left(\frac{1/2-(-1)}{1-(-1)}\right)\left(\frac{1/2-(-1)}{1-(-1)}\right)\tag 3\\
&=\left(\frac{3/2}{2}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{9}{16}
\end{align*}
where:

- $(1)$ is true since if I want the max to be less than $1/2$, then both $X$ and $Y$ have to be less than $1/2$
- $(2)$ is true by independence
- (3) is true since the probability we want geometrically is
  $$\frac{\text{distance from $-1$ to $1/2$}}{\text{distance from $-1$ to $1$}}.$$

  ---

You stated "the where $[X,Y]$ is less than half divided by the total area", but this is
$$\frac{\text{Area less than half}}{\text{Total area}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}(1/2-(-1)}{1} = \frac{3}{4}$$
but this only accounts for one random variable $X$ or $Y$. It needs to be the case that $X$ **and** $Y$ follow this, so you must square:
$$P(M\leq 1/2) = P(X\leq 1/2)P(Y\leq 1/2) = \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4} = \frac{9}{16}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I calculated using this way the blue shaded area is$\frac{9}{4}$and the total area is $4$ . Hence the probability will be  $\frac{9}{4}*\frac{1}{4}$[image: uni]

Comment: i did this way @probablyme

Comment: Wow, I did not get your message, I just happen to check back. I don't think this is right. I think this approach was lucky. I think you need to have the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ but it just happens to be $1$. However, I am not sure. I think the safest approach is my approach. Sorry if this makes more confusion.